# I'm getting half of my Kivy program to run

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Hello I have placed my files below. I'm running into the issue of only getting half of my Kivy program to run. The way it is now I can only get the ScreenManager to run. The buttons created in the KV file under `<LevelsWindow>`, `<GameWindow>`, and `<SuccessWindow>` are the only buttons I see. When clicked they do work as expected (switch to each screen).

However, if I adjust my KV file by removing the `<Touch>:` and having everything under `FloatLayout:` decrement the indent, by 1 tab size, and then increment `WindowManager:` and the three lines below it by one tab size. My code will run the FloatLayout section and show the Buttons (1-10) along with printing "pressed #" when clicked but the ScreenManager section no longer works. The Button appears but nothing happens when pressed.

I believe I need to add_widget somewhere but I'm not sure. Can someone guide me as to what I am doing wrong and how to resolve?

file:my.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
<Button>:
    font_size:25
    size_hint: .1, .1

<Touch>:
    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            id:btn1
            pos_hint:{"x":.25, "top":1}
            text:"1"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":.35, "top":1}
            text:"2"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.45, "top":1}
            text:"3"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.55, "top":1}
            text:"4"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.65, "top":1}
            text:"5"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.25, "y":0.8}
            text:"6"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.35, "y":0.8}
            text:"7"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.45, "y":0.8}
            text:"8"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.55, "y":0.8}
            text:"9"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.65, "y":0.8}
            text:"10"
            on_press:app.pressed(self)

WindowManager:
    LevelsWindow:
    GameWindow:
    SuccessWindow:

<LevelsWindow>:
    name: "levels"
    Button:
        text:"Go to Gameboard"
        on_press: app.root.current = "board"

<GameWindow>:
    name: "board"
    Button:
        text:"right or wrong"
        on_press: app.root.current = "correct"

<SuccessWindow>:
    name: "correct"
    Button:
        text: "Go Home"
        on_press: app.root.current = "levels"
```

file:Myapp.py

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class LevelsWindow(Screen):
    pass

class GameWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SuccessWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Touch(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, Touch):
        pass

    def on_touch_move(self, Touch):
        pass

    def on_touch_up(self, Touch):
        pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def pressed(self, instance):
        name = instance.text
        print "pressed " + name

    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The way i see it you don't reference Touch anywhere else ? i think you are allowed only one root widget in the .kv file ? see [Rule Context](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#rule-context),  when u indent `WindowManager` and delete the <Touch> line, you turn the `FloatLayout` to a root rule, in the second case `WindowManager` is the root rule, and because you don't explicitly add an Instance of <Touch> to it, it will not be rendered.

Comment: So I have been playing around with it more and you are right, I do get the error kv can only have 1 root, when I make `WindowManager` and `FloatLayout` roots without the brackets.

As I mentioned I have been playing around and I modified my KV file shown above to include `Touch:` inside the `<LevelsWindow>:` code on the same indentation level as `Button:`

When I run this code the ScreenManager and changing screens work as expected. The ten buttons that come from the `<Touch>:` section above are all crammed together in a 1x1 box bottom left.

Comment: I assume this is because that is the default location when adding a widget. I tried using pos_hint{ } and size_hint:  to make the FloatLayout fill the entire screen but the buttons just float around in the 1x1 box instead of filling the screen.

Comment: Maybe inherit from a Layout directly and not from the widget class.

Comment: @fins I've been busy and didn't have time to make it back to this. Being new I had to figure out what you meant by inherit from a Layout instead of a widget class. And you were exactly right. I didn't even know I was inheriting from a widget class (just blindly following a tutorial and trying to make it work for my situation). Thank you very much for your help.

For those who may run into this, in my python script I had to change my code from:

`class Touch(widget):`
to
`class Touch(FloatLayout)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may run into this, in my python script I had to inherit from FloatLayout instead of Widget. So, I changed my code from: class Touch(widget): to class Touch(FloatLayout)